# Ripple Effect direction issue

Tags: android, animation, layout, ripple, rippledrawable

When I touch the border of my layout (linear layout with a RippleDrawable as background) the ripple effect does't start in the clicked point but in
also the ripple propagates to the center.

`RippleDrawable drawable = new RippleDrawable(ColorStateList.valueOf(pressedColor), null, getRippleMask(baseColor));
this.setBackground(drawable);`

I also tried to use the `setHotspot` method using as coordinates (0,0) and it doesn't start in the upper left point.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do. You want the ripple to start in the top left regardless of where the user touched the `View`?

Comment: No I want to start the ripple effect exactly where the user tap on the view.

Comment: That is the default behavior. You must have done something terribly wrong to break this, but without seeing the relevant parts of your code nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the method `setHotspotBound(x,y,x,y)` before `setHotspot(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

try this  method may be it's useful for you

```
private void startRippleAnimation(View v, float x, float y){
   Drawable background = v.getBackground();
   if(background instanceof RippleDrawable){
     RippleDrawable ripple = (RippleDrawable)background;
     ripple.setHotspot(x, y);
     ripple.setVisible (true, true);
   }

}
```

Comment: It start where I want but the animations goes to the center instead a linear circular propagation